# a slight "break" in her voice

Tags: word-usage

I came across an unfamiliar use of "break" [here](https://www.bbc.com/news/uk-60352112).

> In full dress uniform, Dame Cressida Dick delivered her resignation speech on the balcony of New Scotland Yard, a slight **break** in her voice as she described the "honour and privilege" of leading the country's biggest police force.

I know "break" is to separate suddenly or violently into two or more pieces, but this meaning doesn't make sense in this sentence.
In this context, what "break" means?

Answer (score 2):

The intended meaning is that their voice is *faltering* - almost giving out. Sometimes this denotes the speaker is upset, or that they are struggling to speak for some other reason.

This example is slightly unusual - it is more common to say that a voice has '*cracks*' rather than 'breaks', although we do sometimes say that someone's voice is "breaking".

One reason why we are less likely to say "a break in their voice" is because it sounds more like the speaker *paused*. "A break in *speech*" is a common way of describing a pause.

Note also that saying someone's voice is "breaking" is an idiomatic way of describing an adolescent male's voice deepening during puberty, another reason why "cracking" or even simply "faltering" is probably a better choice in most contexts.